# R: error en ifelse ("sin valor por omisión")

Tags: r

Quiero crear la variable "confinamiento" con los siguientes valores:0 para los meses anteriores a marzo de 2020,1 para los meses de marzo a agosto de 2020 y 2 desde agosto de 2020 a diciembre 2020.
He probado esto:

```
tablas_unidas3$confinamiento<-ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO<2020,0,

                              ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO==2020 & tablas_unidas3$MES<=02,0,
                              ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO==2020 & tablas_unidas3$MES>=03 & tablas_unidas3$MES<=08,1,
                              ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO==2020 & tablas_unidas3$MES>=09 & tablas_unidas3$MES<=12,2))))
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> El argumento "no" está ausente, sin valor por omisión

Comment: En el código que muestras tienes un paréntesis `)` de más al final

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que falta el valor a asignar si es `FALSE` el tercer `ifelse()`.  Aunque en tus datos nunca vaya a ser `FALSE` la función requiere tres argumentos: la prueba condicional, el resultado para `TRUE` y el resultado para `FALSE`. En los casos anteriores el tercer argumento es otro `ifelse()`, pero en el último no hay ninguno.

Este código probablemente funcione, agrega `NA` como resultado si el tercer `ifelse()` es `FALSE`.

```
ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO==2020 & tablas_unidas3$MES<=02, 0,
       ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO==2020 & tablas_unidas3$MES>=03 & tablas_unidas3$MES<=08, 1,
              ifelse(tablas_unidas3$ANO==2020 & tablas_unidas3$MES>=09 & tablas_unidas3$MES<=12,2, NA)  #Aquí agrego el tercer argumento, NA
              )
       )
```

Además en el código hay un paréntesis de más, como indica Oscar G